# Removing section numbering from markdown cells in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I type "## Prepare python environment" into the cell, it prepends a number. How do I remove this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any  jupyter notebook extensions installed or enabled?

Comment: This shouldn't happen with Markdown by default as ## is only used to set a level 2 heading. Check for any custom editor settings that may have interfered if no extensions exist as commented above.